# PowerShell unable to find type [VMware.VimAutomation.Vds.Impl.V1.VmwareVDPortgroupImpl]

Tags: powershell, exception, powercli

Currently I'm having a strange problem using the PowerCLI Api from VMware.
I wrote a function that needs an `VMware.VimAutomation.Vds.Impl.V1.VmwareVDPortgroupImpl` Object as parameter, but every time I provide such an object it errors out.
While debugging, I found that not even assigning this Object to another Variable with the same type.

```
PS vi:\IX-eShelter> [VMware.VimAutomation.Vds.Impl.V1.VmwareVDPortgroupImpl]$t = Get-VDPortgroup -Name "dv-test-vlan" | Get-Member
Unable to find type [VMware.VimAutomation.Vds.Impl.V1.VmwareVDPortgroupImpl].
At line:1 char:1
+ [VMware.VimAutomation.Vds.Impl.V1.VmwareVDPortgroupImpl]$t = Get-VDPo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (VMware.VimAutom...VDPortgroupImpl:TypeName) [], RuntimeExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

I already tried the following:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("VMware.VimAutomation.Vds.Impl.V1.VmwareVDPortgroupImpl")
Add-Type -AssemblyName "VMware.VimAutomation.Vds.Impl"
```

Edit:
My Function:

```
function New-VMDeployment {Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$false,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][VMware.VimAutomation.Vds.Impl.V1.VmwareVDPortgroupImpl]$port)
Write-Host $port;
};
```

I'm calling it like that:

```
$deployment = [PSCustomObject]@{ "port" = Get-VDPortgroup -Name "dv-test-vlan";};
$deployment | New-VMDeployment;
```

Comment: Edit your question to include your function and how you are using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the implementation (Impl) type has broken for distributed port groups. You should be able to switch over to the Types type and find it operational.

I would suggest modifying the function to read like:

```
function New-VMDeployment {
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Position=0,
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$false,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)
        ]
        [VMware.VimAutomation.Vds.Types.V1.VmwareVDPortgroup]$port
    )

    Write-Host $port
}
```

Additional information: https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2016/04/powercli-best-practice-correct-use-strong-typing.html

Comment: I don't understand why VMware made it that way, but thanks. That would solve the riddle.Normally in powershell if you don't know the exact type you just do a ".GetType().FullName", but here...